# npm non-destructive update

Tags: node.js, npm, typescript

I'm making a node.js project in Typescript and some of the packages don't have the built-in *.d.ts declaration files, so I went to DefinitelyTyped and got the files and added them to the node packages. The issue is, that when I do an npm update, the files get removed: is there a way for I can update my node packages without it removing these "unmanaged"  files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s there a way for I can update my node packages without it removing these "unmanaged" files?

Use tsd + tsd.json to manage these *out of node_modules*.

More on tsd : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd

Comment: I am using TSD, the thing is that I've been putting the DefinitelyTyped files in the same directory as the node packages (and, when necessary, renaming the DefinitelyTyped file to match the name of the file it's emulating) - this is because I don't know how to tell my program where the emulated JS files are. If I don't do that, then when I run the program it has no idea where the *.js file is that the *.d.ts file is referring to.

Comment: Oh nevermind I see what you mean: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#link-to-bundled-definitions thank you, I'll try that when I get home tonight

Comment: Idk if there's a bug, but when I install Request it installs the dependencies but not the actual request.d.ts file

Comment: Also tsd link does nothing

Comment: Late update but I am using TSD and it works very nicely. My main issue here was not understanding that I only needed the *.d.ts file for the compiler's sake, I mistakenly thought the *.d.ts file had to be in the same node module directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tsd` tool to download TypeScript definitions for the packages and then reference them using `///<reference path="" />` comments at the top of your `.ts` files before `import` command is used.

TypeScript 1.6 also supports new [mechanism](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages) so that you can send a pull request to a package maintainer who wrote a JS package and if she is willing to add support for TypeScript, it can work out of box if she adjusts `package.json`:

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "author": "Vandelay Industries",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./lib/foo.js",
    "typings": "./lib/foo.d.ts"
}
```